# Copy and refine the default Search Result inside my Search Service 2013. what is the correct appraoch to follow

Tags: 2013, search, administration, configuration, result-source

I am working on a sharepoint 2013 server.now i want to exclude all the pages that are linked to a certain term from the search result. to do so i did the following steps:-

1. i went to "Central administration" >> "Managed Services" >> "Search service" >> "Result Sources"
2. Copy the default entity which is "Local sharepoint result":-
   [image]
3. after that i modify existing query , where i added the following < "cancelled">> at the end of the query, as follow:-
   [image]
4. and i set the new result source as the default.

now i test the new Result source and seems it is working as expected, where any page that are linked to a wiki category = cancelled will be  excluded from the search result.so can anyone adivce if i followed the correct approach to exclude certain pages from the search result ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your farm is created and if you have one search site or multiple ones is hard to say. However, if this condition is true in all environments and all site collections, then your approach is the best approach IMO.

Comment: now i have on-premise sharepoint server 2013. and i do nothave a search site collection... but i have one web application , and this web application have 6 site collections. one of the site collection is of type enterprise wiki and i want to exclude all the wiki pages that have the WikiCategory= "cancelled".. but now i still have the old default result source "local sharepoint result",, so how will sharepoint chose which source to use ? or it will only use the defualt one , which is the new result source i have created ?

Comment: edit  search results page (results.aspx), and edit the search results web part. Click on change the query and switch to the advanced mode and you should be able the result source (I was able to do it on o365, but I am sure it is the same on 2013)

Comment: but why i need to edit the result.aspx page and its results web part ? what is the problem in my approach of modifying the Result Source?? , you said in ur reply "...then your  approach is the best approach IMO"....?? so not sure i understand you r point ,, i mean what are the differences between editing the result source for the SSA and between editing the search.aspx page ?